# How to replace first time in raw into 0 minutes using panda python

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have a dataset with time. Here My first time is 6:00:00 a.m. Here I want to replace every start time into 0 minutes. I checked the answers of "Convert timedelta to total seconds" and the answers are not related to my question.
I tried so many replace code. But it didn't work. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
 Here I upload the code what I tried?

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('l.csv')
data= pd.DataFrame(dataset,columns=['date','time'])
dtwithoutseconds = dt.replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
```

my dataset:

[My csv file.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fi8S7H2Lx9ob2icGgII7mC3-EMZ2JF6xLcQg50G05Rs/edit#gid=0)

[image]

As you can see in the image , in every start time in every day should be the 0 minutes. 
After replacing the start time into 00:00:00 then add 60 minutes 60 minutes  till to next day start time.

```
start_time = 0 minutes

second_time = 60 minutes   

third_time =  120 minutes

till to 

next_day start time again = 0 minutes
```

Error is coming while typing CSMaverick code. Here I upload the image of the error:

[image]

According to the cs95 last code, it gave me a big error

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('l.csv')
data= pd.DataFrame(dataset,columns=['date','time'])
data['time'] -= data.at[0, 'time']; data['time_in_sec'] =    data['time'].dt.total_seconds()
 print(data['time'])
```

Error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: df.assign(Date=df.Date.dt.round('H'))

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.round.html

Comment: Please indicate your expected output. Should it be [0:00:00, 1:00:00, ...]?

Comment: @cs95 Yes, after replacing start time into 0 seconds. Then add 60 minutes into it (one hour) for next time. [00:00:00 , 01:00:00,02:00:00............... next day (start time) = 00:00:00 ]

Comment: Does `df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time']); df['time'] -= df.at[0, 'time']`?

Comment: @cs95 Yes It's working. Thank you for helping me. Can I ask one question from you? If I want to display it in minutes, then what I have to change in you code?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to contain text instead of an image, and indicate your expected output? I will write an answer with the info you're asking for.

Comment: @CSMaverick When I tried your code It gave me an error " Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values" . Here I paste the image of error.

Comment: @cs95 Yes I edited my  question. Not in a minutes, Sorry I just want to show my time in seconds. I hope you can understand it and you will help me to solve this with new code.

Comment: Is `df['time'].dt.total_seconds()` what you need?

Comment: @cs95 So I have to write this after your earlier code isn't it? But If I wrote this nothing changed It is displaying same as one hour. [00:00:00 , 01:00:00, 02:00:00, 03:00:00, 04:00:00, 05:00:00 , 06:00:00, 07:45:00, 09:00:00, 10:00:00,11:00:00, 12:00:00]

Comment: Full code: `df['time'] -= df.at[0, 'time']; df['time_in_sec'] = df['time'].dt.total_seconds()`

Comment: @cs95 Sorry when I typed your code it gave me a big error. Here I upload it

Comment: You should have also run `df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'])` before running the code above.

Comment: @cs95 I tried it, error gone, but results are same. Nothing chsnged. It didn't convert into seconds. It is displaying one hour one hour.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it worked for me. You are checking the wrong column or whatever.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195476/discussion-between-awa-and-cs95).